# Preserve session after redirect?

Tags: php, session, redirect

if I var_dump my session variable before calling the redirect function, it looks okay. However, after redirecting to an external Clickabnk's payment page, I'm no longer able to access my session variable on the page after payment.

I'm redirecting using the function below :

```
public function redirect($url) {
if(!headers_sent()) {
    //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit();
} else {
    //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
    exit();
}
exit();
}
```

I'm using session_start on all scripts where I'm using sessions.

The page below is the one that makes the redirection

```
<?php 
if(!session_id())  session_start();

require_once("core.php");
$core = new coreOptions();
$options = $core->getChosenOptions();
$numOptions = count($options);


$url = "";


switch($numOptions) {
case 1:
$url = $core->url1Options;
break;
case 2:
$url = $core->url2Options;
break;
case 3:
$url = $core->url3Options;
break;
case 4:
$url = $core->url4Options;
break;
case 5:
$url = $core->url5Options;
break;
case 6:
$url = $core->url6Options;
break;
case 7:
$url = $core->url7Options;
break;
case 8:
$url = $core->url8Options;
break;
case 9:
$url = $core->url9Options;
break;
default:
$url = $core->urldefaultOptions;
break;

}


$core->redirect($url);
exit();

?>
```

Below is the content of core.php

```
.....
// get options
public function getChosenOptions(){
if (isset($_SESSION["chosenOptions"])) return $_SESSION["chosenOptions"];
return false;
}

// set options
public function setChosenOptions($c) {
$_SESSION["chosenOptions"] = $c;
}

 .....
 // function to redirect to given page
public function redirect($url) {
if(!headers_sent()) {
    //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit();
} else {
    //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
    exit();
}
exit();
}
.....
```

The page below is the one I want to access the $_SESSION["chosenOptions"] from.  Why the page below cannot access the session variable although it was set correctly in the page that makes the redirection? :

```
 <?php if(!session_id())  session_start();


require_once("core.php");
$core = new coreOptions();
$uid = $core->uid();
$options = $core->getChosenOptions();
var_dump($options); // this line shows NULL. Why ?
if (empty($options)) exit("Options Is Empty");

if (count((array)$options)>0) {

try {
    $conn = new PDO() // stripped conn data
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO availablecommands (for_whom, oname, is_available) VALUES (:fw, :on, :ia)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

    foreach($options as $o) {
    $statement->bindValue(":fw", $uid);
    $statement->bindValue(":on", $o);
    $statement->bindValue(":ia", 1);
    $count = $statement->execute();
    $conn = null;       // Disconnect

    }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }



}


$core->redirect("dashboard.php");



?>
```

Comment: Perhaps [session_write_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) might be of help?

Comment: Is it possible that you provide a fully verifiable code example? Currently from what you provided, it doesn't seem that it should fail.

Comment: @DenisV Updated now with copy / paste

Comment: @ShikataGaNai well, it's not what I asked for... BTW, you shouldn't post your passwords.

Comment: @DenisV thanks for that.. I will delete that info. you seem to be a good person. :D

Comment: @user3739658: `session_write_close()` will definitively destroy the current session. That's quite the opposite of what OP wants ....

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully [session_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php). Change your code accordingly:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['oldid']) || $_SESSION['oldid'] !== session_id() )
{
   // new session started ... ?
}
$_SESSION['oldid'] = session_id();

 ...
```

You need to manually check whether the current session is the old one or if a new session has been started to what extent ever.